# Internal compiler error: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1 at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.ParameterizedTypeBinding.substitute

Tags: eclipse, openimaj

i have been trying to use OpenImaj Lib and when i run eclipse
this error appears :

org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.ParameterizedTypeBinding.substitute(ParameterizedTypeBinding.java:1190)

what can i do with that ?

Comment: Possibly Eclipse bug [400359](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=400359) which has no resolution at the moment

Comment: thanks for responded,
what can i do with this ?